# Как сделать запись в файл в PHP? Чтобы одна информация стиралась, а другая записывалась?

Tags: php

В TXT-файле есть только одна строка.
Какую функцию нужно использовать, чтобы эта строка
стиралась, и на её место записывалась новая?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
file_put_contents($filename,$string)
```

по-умолчанию, именно это и делает